# Melee Class - Auto run to target

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm a Jedi Knight in SWTOR and being a melee class, I find quite annoying having to run to follow my target when it's being pushed back by a party member.

Is there an option to auto run at hitting range of the current target when I cast an attack?

Comment: Currently there are no built-in game mechanics for this. And no add-ons, mods, nor scripts are allowed. So no; you have to do the leg work.

Comment: @Mufasa: Awww. No one noticed my pun...  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an auto run button which you can configure, as I did, to something like the thumb button on your mouse. Then you can point at a target and hit auto run, but you'll have to aim at them.

There is a follow mechanic in game but it only works on fellow player characters!

Comment: tl;dr version: No, there isn't a way to do that.

Comment: I find coming with at least a helpful solution better.

Comment: I'm not complaining; your workarounds are acceptable and the only ones available for now, yes. My comment was clarifying that this wasn't necessarily a _solution_ to the problem, but they were little things you could try that would minimize the problem. (Which is all Bioware is letting us do for now.)

Comment: It does NEED a follow, I asked this question of myself during the beta! Let's hope

Comment: Last night I tried to configure caps-lock as auto-run, but annoyingly that doesn't seem possible. Rather a shame as it seems to be the logical key to use to me.