# Is there a "Right click to move to" in The Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there a "Right click to move to" option like there is in World of Warcraft?

I cannot seem to find if there an option like this. It would be helpful/easier to move around and interact with quest objects to simply right click on the object and your character automatically moves to it and interact with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate (not sure): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42386/melee-class-auto-run-to-target

Comment: The only reason WoW had this feature was because it was part of the Warcraft series, and previous Warcraft games used "Right-click-to-move-to."

Comment: I don't think comparing a MMO to a RTS is a correct way to cite "the only reason".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some discussion about this on the swtor forums and from what ive been able to tell this feature does not presently exist. From what ive found aswell it doesnt appear that this is something thats currently on the block for addition to the game.
However, id expect that at some point it possibly does get added if possible.

I dont remeber seeing it in the options for the game either personally. However when I get on this evening ill verify that and update this response should there be an option for it I somehow missed aswell.

Sorry....

Comment: Yeah I dug through the every menu option and couldn't find it. Was hoping that it was just something I missed and someone else found it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of is holding down both right and left at same time and u will move. Also but not really usefull is putting yourself on auto run and then u can right click to move but it's more of a pain.